# On select highlight related table cell on xy axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a table which looks like a Chart.

**Quick View:**

[image]

How can I make this table work like area selection chart? For example if I select `6`, `the (x, y) of element 6 is (2, 1)`. So the minimum related area include elements at the `positions (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,1)` should be highlighted. Therefore, the grids `'0,3,1,4,2,6'` will be highlighted.
Like this:

[image]

Similarly,

-if I select `3` it will highlight `0,3` Grids

[image]

-if I Select 2 it will highlight `0,1,2` Grids

[image]

I know very less JS to make this type of actions. Any help will save my day.
This my **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ur4YTovDKI1FAlqzsQCn?p=preview)**

Comment: There are two '6' in your chart table so it's unclear the logic used in your example to highlight 6,4,3,0,1,2.

Comment: Sorry I just updated

Comment: I don't quite understand your logic.. Since the selection is based on a minimum area criteria how come `0,1,2` get highlighted when you select `2` and not `2,6,9`? The same goes for `6` (`6,2` or `6,9` instead of `6,4,3,0,1,2`).

Comment: sorry my English is slow but. I mean it will work as xy axis 0 is the center here so 2 is on x axis. 2 has no y axis. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am with @kidA on what I understood. I think you need to explain a bit more clear. Maybe show some more pictures of what gets highlighted when you select 2. In my mind, if you select 2, 2,6 and 9 will be selected because it does have a y axis..its up

Comment: I have added images what will be there. It will work like a graph paper with grids

Answer (score 2):

So, like others, I am puzzled a bit by what you are trying to do.  There seems to be a break in consistency with the examples you gave.  If you want to highlight along the x,y axis then it would be a little different than what you have shown.
Either way, I threw this together, perhaps it will get you started:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gWtBMbAOmtoQ8scAP4Ef)

It does what is shown in picture 1 and 3, though not picture 2.

```
  $scope.boxes = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
  $scope.boxClass = ['cOne', 'cTwo', 'cThree', 'cFour', 'cFive', 'cSix', 'cSeven', 'cEight', 'cNine']

  $scope.boxes.reverse();
  console.log($scope.boxes)

  $scope.findChecked = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.boxes.length; i++){
      if ($scope[$scope.boxes[i]]) {
        $scope.currentBox = 9 - i
        console.log($scope.currentBox)
        break;
      }
    } 
    for (var x = 0; x < $scope.boxClass.length; x++) {
      if (x < $scope.currentBox) {
        $scope[$scope.boxClass[x]] = 'checked'
      } else { 
        $scope[$scope.boxClass[x]] = ''
      }
    }
    }
```

If you want to highlight along along x,y coordinates, you can do it like this:

```
  var row1 = ['cOne', 'cTwo', 'cThree'];
  var row2 = ['cFour', 'cFive', 'cSix'];
  var row3 = ['cSeven', 'cEight', 'cNine'];
  var col1 = ['cOne', 'cFour', 'cSeven'];
  var col2 = ['cTwo', 'cFive', 'cEight'];
  var col3 = ['cThree', 'cSix', 'cNine'];

  var rows = [row1, row2, row3];
  var cols = [col1, col2, col3];

  $scope.setXY = function(x, y) {
    console.log(x, y)
    var i = 0, z = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      for(z = 0; z < rows[i].length; z++) {
        $scope[rows[i][z]] = '';
        $scope[cols[i][z]] = '';
      }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      $scope[rows[y][i]] = 'checked';
      $scope[cols[x][i]] = 'checked';
    }
  }
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bKqbJZXBKunPQfNrBsiG?p=preview) (I used buttons this time...works a bit better)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It's closer what I wanted. What I was trying to make it like this :
http://i61.tinypic.com/6rhe2q.jpg
Black dots are the grid points and red are the area. This is my main concept.

Comment: ok i understand..but with a small grid like this, is there much use to it?

Comment: basically, you want it to draw a rectangle from 0,0 to whatever coordinates.

Comment: Yes ! now I am able to make understand someone :)

Comment: I used this small grid for demo purpose only on my original it will be 10x10

Comment: See my updated answer.  It highlights along x,y.  Not quite what you were trying to do, but you should have enough to go on now to figure it out yourself.

Comment: that last plnkr you did is exactly what I thought the OP was asking